# UIViews to a vertical 3D stack

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios7

I am about to do an application which exactly works like Safari running in iOS7. I have no idea how to bring the UIViews to a vertical 3D stack on a button click and select one. Kindly share your ideas to which technology I should adopt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody except Apple can tell you how they do it in Safari, but it's certainly achievable using a UICollectionView and a custom layout. The layout can specify the following things about each cell:

- Center
- Size
- Z-ordering
- 3D transform

All of which can be recalculated on-the-fly during scrolling.

I'd definitely start there.